# ember model -making a table of items click for detail

Tags: ember.js

I am just learning emberjs and have been given a barebones task.

I have a table of users displayed from my model. To the side of the table, I have an area where it will display details of a selected user. Thus:

```
ID FNAME LNAME         | DETAIL: User 2
1  Andy  Ashford       | First: Betty
2  Betty Beckett       | Last: Beckett
                       | Phone: 222-222-2222
```

I've got the LEFT side working, but not the RIGHT side.

(I'm using **Mirage** to load data. I could not seem to get **http-mocks** to work).

Two questions:

1. Should I

   - route this directly within script or
   - should I use the path? i.e. When just the users table is displayed, my path is /users/, but when I click on user 1, I could set the path to /user/1, then do all my logic from there.
2. With either method, how do I deliver the specific user data to the user-detail component? How do I point the model at the view?

Here is my **Mirage/config.js** (don't know why Mirage keeps data in a config file, but...)

```
this.get('/users', function() {
    return {
        data: [{
            type: 'users',
            id: 1,
            attributes: {
                fname: 'Andy',
                lname: 'Ashford',
                phone: '111-111-1111',
            }
        }, {
            type: 'users',
            id: 2,
            attributes: {
                fname: 'Betty',
                lname: 'Beckett',
                phone: '222-222-2222',
            }
        }]
    };
});
```

My **models/user.js** just looks like this:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';

export default Model.extend({
    fname: attr(),
    lname: attr(),
    phone: attr()
});
```

My main **templates/components/user-list.hbs** (this is working - table on left, though detail on right has no data):

```
<table class="with-detail"><tr>
        <td class="table-overview">
            <table class="user-table">
                {{#each users as |user|}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{user.id}} </td>
                    <td>{{user.fname}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.lname}}</td>
                </tr>
              {{/each}}
            </table>
        </td>
        <td class="table-detail">
            <!-- Show all data of user X -->
            <!--{{user-detail}}-->

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My **templates/components/user-detail.hbs** (I can see the labels in the detail, so I'm calling the template, but no data):

```
First name: {{user.fname}} //these don't work of course
Last name: {{user.lname}}
Phone: {{user.phone}}
```

This is what I've been trying to do with the **router.js**:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('users', { 
      path: 'users', 
  });
  this.route('user', { 
      path: 'user/:id' 
  });
});
```

And for good measure, there are additionally some routes.
**routes/users.js**:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('user');
    }
});
```

**routes/user.js**:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.query('user', { id: 1 });    
    }
});
```

(and why so many route files?)

If I hit user/1 directly, I see nothing - no table, no detail (presumably because /users/ and its model have gone away).

I'm sort of stumped.

Comment: Upon reflection, I see that - when showing the details of a user - I still need to display the table of all users. So it seems to me I should NOT use the path method (/user/1) for the detail, since the table data would not be available. I guess that answers my first question: I should deliver the details for a user (which I already have) internally, via javascript, not via the path.

Comment: Can you provide an ember-twiddle? I think you should nest your detail route under your list route.

Comment: You should use a detail route for this. The way Ember works the data for the `users` route will be retrieved before rendering the nested detail route.

Comment: Started it here: 
https://ember-twiddle.com/6369f7c09a49eb1d23e9b1c60fa9662e?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C

Comment: I seem to have missed some element in transferring it to the twiddle. My data isn't appearing even on the left side.
I'm not quire sure how to transfer it and simplify. Where am I even pointing the model at the template?

Comment: @jon: no such thing as a Detail route that I can find. Is that a nested route?

Comment: Yes. By 'detail' I mean by the a master-detail interface: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master%E2%80%93detail_interface

Comment: Yes I know, I just don't know how to do it in ember.
I can't even get step 1 of my twiddle working, let alone step 2. I don't know what part I'm missing.
https://ember-twiddle.com/6369f7c09a49eb1d23e9b1c60fa9662e?openFiles=models.users.js%2C&route=%2Fusers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your question is a bit general, I've created this solution for a different SO question, but it should serve as a good demonstration of what I believe you want.

Have a look at this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/28d216680b61424583aca32e9048dd2a?openFiles=router.js%2C&route=%2Fgames%2Fgame%2F1%2Fcomments), and let me know if this is what you had in mind.

The corresponding routing structure for this app is

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('games', function(){
    this.route('game', { path: '/game/:language_id' }, function(){
        this.route('comments') 
    })        
  })
```

So you'll see a list of games on the left and on clicking one, a detail of it on the right, with comments loaded.

Comment: I've followed your twiddle. Now I see my templates, but no data in them. I will post to GitHub.

Comment: This is my barebones project, using master-detail view. I see the template no but no data. Hopefully it's something minor. https://github.com/DavesBrain/Orbcare-test

Comment: Ah. A bit of fiddling with the model attributes has got me seeing data! Thank you!