# ember bind-attr class is not being set by controller

Tags: ember.js

I'm creating a master-detail table.
Before an item has been chosen, the details should not be visible, only becoming visible on clicking of an item.

The reason I'm using a class is because the table is normally 100% width, and it changes size when the detail pops up. This is not implemented yet. Right now, I just want the 'with-details' class to be inserted into the div when I click in the < li >

Here is a rough twiddle:
https://ember-twiddle.com/f35bb4b593394d955460a83a10f092a4

In my template, the < li > has an action:

```
<li {{action 'showDetails'}}>
```

which fires the showDetails action in my controller (I know it's firing because of the :) in console):

```
  withDetails: false,
  actions: {
        showDetails: function() {
            console.log(":)");
            this.set('withDetails', true);
        }
    }
```

which should add the with-detail class to my details div:

```
<div {{bind-attr class=":game-details withDetails"}} >
```

which should match my CSS:

```
.game-details {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.game-details.with-details {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

It should be that easy. What am I missing?

**[ EDIT ]** I just learned this trick:

Wrong:

```
<div class="game-details" {{bind-attr class="withDetails"}}>
```

Right:

```
<div {{bind-attr class=":game-details withDetails"}}>
```

which shows the div, but does not attach a with-details class I can target.

Comment: @TameBurger: this is building on top of your Games twiddle from this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898364/ember-model-making-a-table-of-items-click-for-detail

Comment: Where fif you get the info that you need to use `bind-attr`? Just curious if we can improve the Ember documentation.

Answer (score 2):

[`bind-attr` is deprecated since 1.13](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_bind-attr) and disabled since 2.0. Instead, you should use embedded `{{if}}` in your class attribute, like so:

```
<div class="game-details {{if withDetails "with-details"}}">
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

Comment: OK, I'd tried that, but now I get a Cannot read property 'yield' of undefined. Here is a twiddle I'm working on: https://ember-twiddle.com/f35bb4b593394d955460a83a10f092a4
For some reason my close button will not bubble up.